# set double format with 2 decimal places

Tags: java, swing, int, decimal, decimalformat

I have a short equation:

```
double compute,computed2;

compute=getminutes/60;
```

where `getminutes` is `int` and I want to set the equivalent of `compute` with 2 decimal places. `0.00` how can I format the equivalent with 2 decimal places?

Example:

```
compute=45/60 it should be 0.75
```

Here is my work:

```
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("00.00000");
double computed,computed2 = 00.000;

computed=60/getitbyminutes;
df2.format(computed);
computed2=computed-8;
df2.format(computed2);

System.out.printf("%1$.2f",computed);
System.out.println();
System.out.printf("%1$.2f",computed2);
```

the out put will be just like :

```
1.00
7.00
```

Comment: "*compute=45/60 it should be 0.75*" not in Java. try 45.0d/60.0d

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it to Double

```
compute=(Double)getminutes/60;
```

and then use `DecimalFormat` as mentioned by Peter.

Comment: Yeap! thank you this solved my problem. Why is that i can't accept your answer?

Comment: @JonSnow: Glad I could help! What error message you are getting?

Answer (score 11):

Just format the output the right way:

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: compute=45/60 it should be 0.75. my double is not declared... it's an integer.