# printf in Java SE 8u5 - Printing double to 2 decimal places

Tags: java, formatting, decimal, printf

I am new to Java and have been working through a book a buddy of mine is letting me borrow. However, I believe the book may be a bit out of date.

I am trying to print a price, and to do so the book uses the example (packPrice & packVolume are both double variables entered using in.nextDouble()):

```
double pricePerOunce = packPrice / packVolume;

System.out.printf("Price per ounce: %8.2f", pricePerOunce);
System.out.println();
```

However, when I try the exact same code in Java SE 8u5 (Windows 64 bit), I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method printf(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for        
        the arguments (String, double)
```

Does anyone have the remedy to my problem? Let me know if any more information is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, what language compatibility level is it set to? If it's set to 1.4 or below, you'll get this error message. `printf` uses vararg methods, a feature that wasn't introduced until Java 1.5 (aka Java 5).

Answer (score 0):

[Why am I getting a compilation errors with a simple printf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774428/why-am-i-getting-a-compilation-errors-with-a-simple-printf)

"Check that the Compiler compliance level is set to at least 1.5 for your project:

Project > Properties > Java Compiler

if Enable project specific settings is not set, use the Configue Workspace Settings... link on that page to check the global Compiler compliance level."

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way of outputting a double with decimal precision is done like this,

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

This example and similar question can be found here: [set double format with 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082115/set-double-format-with-2-decimal-places)